# How to make TortoiseSVN diff .dot and .dotx Word template files

Tags: svn, tortoisesvn

TortoiseSVN has the amazing ability to diff Microsoft Word document revisions, made possible apparently by a script in `C:\Program Files\TortoiseSVN\Diff-Scripts` which calls out to MS Word to do the diff (instead of using TortoiseMerge to diff them as text files, which of course wouldn't work for Word files).  MS Word itself is able to diff two versions of .dot or .dotx files, using the same user interface "clicks" as diffing two versions of .doc or .docx files, so it would seem that the TortoiseSVN script for .doc and .docx files (`diff-doc.js`) should also work for .dot and .dotx files.

In attempting to enable TortoiseSVN to diff .dot and .dotx files, I edited the first line of `diff-doc.js` from this...

```
// extensions: doc;docx;docm
```

...to this:

```
// extensions: doc;docx;docm;dot;dotx
```

And then I tried using TortoiseSVN to diff a .dot file with its previous version, and it behaved the same as before (TortoiseMerge complained that it wasn't a valid text file).  Thinking perhaps TortoiseSVN only checks the `extensions` comments in the script files once on startup, I rebooted, and still the same behavior.

Am I missing something necessary to make TortoiseSVN diff .dot & .dotx files?  (BTW, I am aware that the .dot extension is used by other programs for things unrelated to MS Word, and I am aware that this makes files with .dot extensions ambiguous with regard to their true file format.)

Comment: The 'extension:' line in the diff scripts is only used once, and whenever you set the diff tools to their default (Settings -> Diff viewer -> Advanced...)

Comment: @Stefan Are you suggesting that the comments are in fact functional, and do in fact "do something"?

Comment: yes, they're used by TSVN to determine the defaults. Was the easiest way to do that: that way, the defaults are stored where they belong and not in some other place.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use the same script, just tell Tortoise how to handle your .dot / .dotx file extension:

```
Right Click -> Tortoise SVN -> Settings -> Diff viewer -> Advanced...
```

You will see a list of current extensions. Select *.docx*, click edit and copy to clipboard the value of *"External program"*.
Close it and click Add..., insert *.dot* as extension, paste value from clipboard to *"External program"* field.

That is all.